# Boundary gradient blowup of a parabolic PDE with an unbounded coefficient

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am exploring the boundary gradient blowup of following parabolic PDE on the semi-infinite strip $(-\infty,0]\times[0,1]$:

Let $0< \alpha < 1/2$.

$\partial_t u(x,t) = -\alpha(1-t)^{\alpha - 1} \partial_x u(x,t) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} u(x,t), \quad (x,t) \in (-\infty,0] \times [0,1]$

with the initial condition $u(x,0)$ a non-negative continuous $L^2$ function with $u(x,0) \to 0$ as $x \nearrow 0$ and $x \searrow -\infty$, (for example, $u(x,0) = |x| e^{-x^2}$),

and boundary conditions $u(0,t) = u(-\infty,t) = u(-\infty,t) = 0$ for $t \in [0,1]$.

I suspect that the solution is bounded but the gradient $\partial_x u(x,t)$ becomes unbounded as $(x,t) \to (0,1)$. In fact, I think

$u(x,1) \sim |x|^{2 \alpha}$ as $x \nearrow 0$,

and

$u(1,t) \sim -(1-t)^{\alpha-1/2}$ as $t \nearrow 1$.

PDEs are not my main area of study and I'm not familiar with the literature. I'd appreciate some pointers and references.

Comment: I've retagged. Both (parabolic) and (gradient) are too general (applicable to too many things). And the (blowup) tag doesn't mean what you think it means (it means the blowup construction in algebraic geometry), not singularity formation for differential equations.

Comment: Also, what values are $\alpha$ allowed to take?

Comment: Thanks Willie. Good points. In my problem $\alpha < 1/2$. For $\alpha \geq 1/2$, the diffusion term dominates the $\partial_x$ term and no singularity is formed. 

Also it is known that the solution $u$ itself remains bounded.

Comment: Another question: you cannot expect blowup for all non-negative continuous $L^2$ data: $u\equiv 0$ is a solution. Are you claiming that for all non-zero data one should expect blow up? Is this backed by numerical studies or perhaps by some sort of heuristics? (Yes, in general it is a good practice to share your "good reason to suspect" if you are asking a question.)

Comment: Lastly, do you mean data is only in $L^2$ with continuity? You do not assume anything on the first derivative level for the data?

Comment: Thanks again Willie. My problem originated in probability theory, as a problem for the heat equation in a non-cylindrical domain $\Omega$. $\Omega$ is bounded on the right by a time dependent function $b(t)$, and unbounded on the right. Let $\Omega := \{ (x,t) : t \in [0,1], x < (1-t)^\alpha  \}$, where $\alpha < 1/2$. Thus the domain has a "cusp" at $t = 1$. In fact, it is an irregular boundary point for the heat equation. 

Now, I will restate the problem in terms of the heat equation in the next comment:

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02310297) and its references may be useful. Similar problems appears to have been somewhat well studied.

The article: "Solutions of the heat equation in domains with singularities" by V. N. Aref'ev and L. A. Bagirov

Comment: Thanks Willie. I have read the article. Unfortunately it only deals with cases when my $\alpha \geq 1/2$ so that no blow-up occurs.